# How to be able to receive dates through CSV with different formats and homogenize them to the format that MySQL / MariaDB handles?

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller, pdo, mariadb

I am currently working in PHP on a web project with MVC architecture. The main task is to upload CSV files that simply contain an identifier number and a date; the problem I am running into is with the date format. The dates that are uploaded are in two different formats:

- dd / mm / yyyy hh: mm
- dd / mm / yyyy hh: mm AM / PM

The structure of the CSV file that is finally received by a table within my database, is the following:

| employee | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 01/01/2021 1:00 p.m. |
| 1001 | 01/01/2021 14:00 |

The problem is that when uploading the CSV file to my database in MariaDB, the required date format is **yyyy-mm-dd hh: mm** (although I have seen that it also accepts **yyyy / mm / dd hh: mm**). What I have been doing to solve this problem is changing the format in the CSV file to conform to what MariaDB accepts before uploading it to the database, but it would seem more practical for the user if this change of format is managed within the code instead of the same user making the change of format in the file before uploading it.

Currently I have the following structure and methods that are responsible for receiving the CSV file and uploading it to the database:

**VIEW (HTML)**:

```
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

 <fieldset>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="file" name="file" required/>
   </div>
      <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="import_file" value="IMPORT"/>
 </fieldset>

  <?php
     $excel = new ControllerEvents();
     $excel ->ctrImportExcel();
  ?>

</form>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
static public function ctrImportExcel()
{
    if(isset($_POST["import_file"])) 
    { 
        $file = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]; 
        $file_open = fopen($file,"r"); 

        while(($data = fgetcsv($file_open, 1000, ",")) !== false)
        {
            $no_empleado = $data[0];
            $date = $data[1]; 

            $table = "events";

            $answer  = ModelEvents::mdlImportExcel($table, $data);
        }

        if($answer=="ok")
        {
            echo"<script>
                Swal.fire({ 
                    title: 'Success!',
                    icon: 'success',
                    confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                    }).then((result)=>{
                        if(result.value){
                            window.location = 'index';
                        }
                    });
            </script>";
                
        }
        else
        {
            echo"<script>
                    Swal.fire({ 
                        title: 'Error!',
                        icon: 'error',
                        confirmButtonText:'Ok'
                        });
                 </script>";
        }
    }
}
```

**MODEL:**

```
<?php
    require_once "connection.php";
    class ModelEvents{

    static public function mdlImportExcel($table,$data)
    {
        $stmt = connection::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO $table(employee,start_event) VALUES(:employee,:start_event)");
            
        $stmt->bindparam(":employee",$data[0],PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindparam(":start_event",$data[1],PDO::PARAM_STR);

        if($stmt->execute()){
            return "ok";
        }else{
            return "error";
        }

        $stmt ->close();
        $stmt = null;
    } 
?>
```

How could I adapt my controller so that upon receipt of the CSV file, the dates are changed to the format that MariaDB accepts? I have tried as follows without success:

`$datos[1] = date_format($datos[1], 'Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your question boils down to "How can I convert datetime strings like '2021-06-01 01:53:00' to 'yyyy-mm-dd' format in PHP?"?

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo, no. I want to convert ```DATETIME``` strings like '01/01/2021 1:00 p.m.' and '01/01/2021 14:00' to 'yyyy-mm-dd', **BUT** I want to handle that convertion in my controller method. I can recieve those both types of ```DATETIME``` string from the CSV file (**dd / mm / yyyy hh: mm** and **dd / mm / yyyy hh: mm AM / PM**).

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php then https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.

Comment: @JorgeDuran Yes, that's what I said. Or maybe what I meant :). Nothing big there though. Have you studied the functions that AbraCadaver linked to? (Hint for future development: If you run `php -a` from the command line you get an interactive interpreter for PHP, just like if you run `python`. Imho it's incredibly useful for testing code. You might want to try that on one of your datetime strings above, with AbraCadaver's functions :))